# svn log not showing all revisions

Tags: svn

I'm rather new to svn, I have mostly been using git.
My question is, how come when I run svn log on this repo:
https://code.google.com/p/gwt-ext/source/list
not all revisions are shown?
For example, I run 
svn log -v http://gwt-ext.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
it doesn't show the latest two revisions (r1878 and r1877) and it doesn't show r1870, and I don't know why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["svn log" not showing all recent commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787065/svn-log-not-showing-all-recent-commits)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because those revisions didn't apply to trunk.

Run `svn log` at the root of the repo if you want to see everything.

Answer (score 7):

You have to do

> svn update

```
$ svn help update
update (up): Bring changes from the repository into the working copy.
usage: update [PATH...]

  If no revision is given, bring working copy up-to-date with HEAD rev.
  Else synchronize working copy to revision given by -r.

  For each updated item a line will be printed with characters reporting
  the action taken. These characters have the following meaning:

    A  Added
    D  Deleted
    U  Updated
    C  Conflict
    G  Merged
    E  Existed
    R  Replaced

  Characters in the first column report about the item itself.
  Characters in the second column report about properties of the item.
  A 'B' in the third column signifies that the lock for the file has
  been broken or stolen.
  A 'C' in the fourth column indicates a tree conflict, while a 'C' in
  the first and second columns indicate textual conflicts in files
  and in property values, respectively.

  If --force is used, unversioned obstructing paths in the working
  copy do not automatically cause a failure if the update attempts to
  add the same path.  If the obstructing path is the same type (file
  or directory) as the corresponding path in the repository it becomes
  versioned but its contents are left 'as-is' in the working copy.
  This means that an obstructing directory's unversioned children may
  also obstruct and become versioned.  For files, any content differences
  between the obstruction and the repository are treated like a local
  modification to the working copy.  All properties from the repository
  are applied to the obstructing path.  Obstructing paths are reported
  in the first column with code 'E'.

  If the specified update target is missing from the working copy but its
  immediate parent directory is present, checkout the target into its
  parent directory at the specified depth.  If --parents is specified,
  create any missing parent directories of the target by checking them
  out, too, at depth=empty.

  Use the --set-depth option to set a new working copy depth on the
  targets of this operation.

Valid options:
  -r [--revision] ARG      : ARG (some commands also take ARG1:ARG2 range)
                             A revision argument can be one of:
                                NUMBER       revision number
                                '{' DATE '}' revision at start of the date
                                'HEAD'       latest in repository
                                'BASE'       base rev of item's working copy
                                'COMMITTED'  last commit at or before BASE
                                'PREV'       revision just before COMMITTED
  -N [--non-recursive]     : obsolete; try --depth=files or --depth=immediates
  --depth ARG              : limit operation by depth ARG ('empty', 'files',
                             'immediates', or 'infinity')
  --set-depth ARG          : set new working copy depth to ARG ('exclude',
                             'empty', 'files', 'immediates', or 'infinity')
  -q [--quiet]             : print nothing, or only summary information
  --diff3-cmd ARG          : use ARG as merge command
  --force                  : force operation to run
  --ignore-externals       : ignore externals definitions
  --changelist [--cl] ARG  : operate only on members of changelist ARG
  --editor-cmd ARG         : use ARG as external editor
  --accept ARG             : specify automatic conflict resolution action
                             ('postpone', 'working', 'base', 'mine-conflict',
                             'theirs-conflict', 'mine-full', 'theirs-full',
                             'edit', 'launch')
                             (shorthand: 'p', 'mc', 'tc', 'mf', 'tf', 'e', 'l')
  --parents                : make intermediate directories

Global options:
  --username ARG           : specify a username ARG
  --password ARG           : specify a password ARG
  --no-auth-cache          : do not cache authentication tokens
  --non-interactive        : do no interactive prompting (default is to prompt
                             only if standard input is a terminal device)
  --force-interactive      : do interactive prompting even if standard input
                             is not a terminal device
  --trust-server-cert      : accept SSL server certificates from unknown
                             certificate authorities without prompting (but only
                             with '--non-interactive')
  --config-dir ARG         : read user configuration files from directory ARG
  --config-option ARG      : set user configuration option in the format:
                                 FILE:SECTION:OPTION=[VALUE]
                             For example:
                                 servers:global:http-library=serf
```

Comment: What question are you answering?

Answer (score 4):

To see all revisions regardless of branch use this command:

```
svn log -r 0:HEAD ^/
```

This should work while on any branch

Answer (score 0):

`svn log` only lists the revision numbers applicable for the branch it is applied to.

If a directory has changes it will list those changes, and *only* those changes in the log.

I.e. r1870 did not apply to that part of the code.