# Why svn log checks the repository availabily, if I run svn log work_copy_path?

Tags: svn

Why **svn log** checks the repository availabily, if I run **svn log *work_copy_path*** only?

#### Details

From http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html

```
svn log [PATH]
```

- checks the commits from work copy

```
svn log URL[@REV] [PATH...]
```

- checks the commits from repo

But if I run

```
svn log [work_copy_path]
```

svn try to connect to repo, and if repo is unavailable - log fails.

#### UPD

If I do not update the wc, and repo contain a new revisions, log wc doesn't show the new repo revisions, unknown to wc. This mean, net request to repo from svn log wc are senseless.

Answer (score 2):

Because Subversion keep history on server.

When you execute `svn log [PATH]` it use `[PATH]` for retrieve associated URL, revision and then internally execute `svn log URL[@REV]`

P.S. Some Subversion clients (TortoiseSVN) can cache log history, so it available even if server is down.

Comment: But why svn log path and svn log repo prints the different results?

Comment: May be I do not get question. Do you mean that `svn log [PATH]` works and `svn log [work_copy_path]` - not? I do not see difference in this comamnds, both has argument path to wc (or inside wc)

Comment: If I do not update the wc, and repo contain a new revisions, log wc doesn't show the new revs, unknown to wc. This mean, net request to repo from svn log wc are senseless.

Comment: > But why svn log path and svn log repo prints the different results? <br> by design. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787065/svn-log-not-showing-all-recent-commits http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.history.html#svn.tour.history.log